# Input filter not filter one by one in android

Tags: android

I use InputFilter to check my String from editText.

```
 final InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {


                @Override
                public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start,
                        int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                    int num = 0;
                    try {
                        num = Integer.parseInt(source.toString());
                        if (!(num > 0 && num < 30)) {
                            return "";
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                    return null;
                }
            };

        etStatDaysCount = (EditText) inflate2.findViewById(R.id.et_settings_days_to_statistics);
        etStatDaysCount.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

But I have a problem. I want to check if user put number <0 or >30 I want to replace this text. This filter check number one by one. So if I put number 56, he check number 5 and after that 6 so this filter let user put number 56 in edit text. I want to check all string which I put in edittext. So if I put 56 he should check number 5 and after that check number 56. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're answering your own question. If the problem is that the filter checks the numbers one by one then don't use it! Just grab the value from the EditText whenever you're ready to test it and make sure it meets your criteria.

```
etStatDaysCount = (EditText) inflate2.findViewById(R.id.et_settings_days_to_statistics);


//when you're ready to look at the value...
String input = etStatDaysCount.getText().toString()
if(input.trim().equals("") || input.matches("\\D") || Integer.valueOf(input) < 0 || Integer.valueOf(input) > 30)
      //this is a value that you don't want
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `TextChangeListener`. It is fired up whenever an input is made to editText.

```
   etStatDaysCount = (EditText) inflate2.findViewById(R.id.et_settings_days_to_statistics);

   etStatDaysCount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3     ) {

                    // you can check every number/alphabet of input here
}
```

If you don't want to check each individual character in your input, you can always do like:

```
String yourInput = etStatDaysCount.getText().toString();

if(Integer.valueOf(yourInput) <0 && Integer.valueOf(yourInput) >30 )
      // undesired value
```

Hope this helps

Comment: if I understand the question correctly, this is precisely the reason the OP is *having a problem.  He/she shouldn't evaluate the digits as they're typed, but all at once when they're done.

Comment: Yeah but I think he couldn't convey his problem properly. I think he wants to check each input individually.